# How to compile curl with latest openssl

Tags: c, linux, curl, openssl

I download curl7.40 source code, and I have already compile openssl
1.0.2 source code, Now I want to compile curl with openssl 1.0.2.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/curl-7.40.0 --with-ssl 
--with-libssl-prefix=/usr/local/openssl-1.0.2

make && make install
```

After I install, I ldd curl library but still link with system default library.

`ldd libcurl.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff2db2e000)
libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0x00007fafb9b6e000)
librtmp.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.0 (0x00007fafb9954000)
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fafb96f5000)
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
(0x00007fafb931b000)
...`

**UPDATE**
After some search, I use below command to config.

`./configure --prefix=/usr/local/curl-7.40.0 --with-ssl=/usr/local/openssl-1.0.2`

But when make install, it will show below error information.

```
../lib/.libs/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `SSLv2_client_method'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: SSLv2 support is removed from openssl 1.0.2. You may have includes from one SSL version and libraries from another. Look at compilation logs. Is there something like `-I/usr/local/openssl-1.0.2/include`?

Comment: yes, openssl remove sslv2 support, but it seems libcurl is still use it. and from some search result that suggest to modify libcurl source code lib/ssluse.c to comments it, but in 7.40, I do not find this file.

Comment: libcurl knows to detect whether openssl has sslv2 support at configure stage. Look at config.log and/or config.h.

Comment: In config.log, I found below information, configure:21938: checking for SSLv2_client_method
configure:21938: gcc -o conftest -O2 -Wno-system-headers  -I/usr/local/openssl-1.0.2/include    -L/usr/local/openssl-1.0.2/lib   conftest.c -lssl -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto   -llber -lldap -lz  >&5
configure:21938: $? = 0
configure:21938: result: yes

Comment: OK so that's the prroblem. Why has it detected a function that's ostensibly not there? You can try to compile their test program manually, with more verbose compiler/linker output and keeping intermediate files.

Comment: hm, Where is test program, I am not familiar with this part. Please give us some detail information.

Comment: The conftest.c you see in the conf.log is the test program. You can find the source in the log and/or in the configure script. The script creates the .c file and compiles it. Beware there are many test programs executed during the configure stage, all called conftest.c, you need the one that reverences SSLv2_client_method.

Comment: Looks like this was a `curl` bug requiring a [code change](https://github.com/curl/curl/commit/577286e0e246c93239726a278cc1cb582b4d19ae); from that commit, it looks like curl-7.47.1 and later should compile cleanly.

Comment: @Castaglia: only for OpenSSL 1.1, which this question was clearly not about!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely with how you have build the OpenSSL library.

It is likely you have built openssl with SSLv2 disabled as some distributions have SSLv2 disable by default.  Look at the `./config` for your system when you are compiling OpenSSL, and find the option that controls the OPENSSL_NO_SSL2 preprocessor flag.
In order to use proper version of openssl while making from source, you can make openssl like this:

```
cd <path-to-openssl-dir>
./config enable-ssl2 enable-ssl3 --prefix=<path-to-openssl-install-dir>
```

Then, you can link your curl version properly to openssl by:

```
./configure --with-ssl=<path-to-openssl-install-dir>
```

Answer (score 0):

`SSLv2_client_method()` is used in lib/vtls/openssl.c, line 1575 with a [check](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/curl-7_40_0/lib/vtls/openssl.c#L134) for availability of this function via [autoconf](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/curl-7_40_0/configure.ac#L1584). It seems to me that autoconf's AC_CHECK_FUNCS incorrectly finds your system installation of openssl which has SSLv2 enabled before `#include`ing your own installation of openssl-1.0.2 which doesn't have `SSLv2_client_method()` and thus assumes the function to be available.

Try passing `CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/openssl-1.0.2/include` or even `"CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/openssl-1.0.2/include -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL2"` as arguments to `./configure` to force `openssl.c` to make do without the `SSLv2_client_method()` incorrectly assumed to be available.